# In Nativescript, is there any way to get an action item in ActionBar by id?

Tags: nativescript

I'm using NativeScript 1.5 and it seems like I cannot get view by id for items in ActionBar.

Or maybe I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion would be appreciated really much.

Comment: That's because Action Items are not views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot get it by id ,anyway  it s only one, you can get it programatically from the page ( args.object) . You can play with the action bar using the ActionBar.titleView in xml where you can put even Layouts (StackLayout) change height, arrange items, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it works in 1.6 on iOS, but crashes on android, 1.7 next week should resolve it

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1691